# How to show merge commit in git log <file>?

Tags: git, merge

I happened to run into a situation when a merge can effectively roll back a commit without any log traceable in any easy way I know of:

```
*   fcfea4c merge   code.txt:1                       other.txt:a
|\
| * b0f6762 conflict code.txt:1                      other.txt:b
* | 9fe5de2 other　　code.txt:2                       other.txt:a
|/
* e0d9522 previous   code.txt：1
* 7a466e5 init    touch code.txt
```

The left branch is `master` and the right branch is `feature`, when merging in `fcfea4c`, there is a conflict in file other.txt (code.txt should be automaticlly merged by git), and if I run `git checkout HEAD~ .`(e0d9522 previous commit) at master and then conclude commit.`git log code.txt` will only show `init(7a466e5)` and `previous(e0d9522)` commit and the `other(9fe5de2)` commit is missing. So is there a easy way to trace what happened to `code.txt` (show `other` and `merge` commits as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --first-parent --graph --all -- code.txt` is the answer, `--first-parent` effectively mean seeing merge as a normal commit on that specific branch (`Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit.`).

Answer (score 1):

You should try instead:

```
git checkout --ours -- others.txt
```

That should preserve the history of the merge while keeping the content you are after.

Comment: Acually the merge is done by others and I am trying to locate the cause of missing commit, it sure take a long time to locate by verifying commit history one by one if this project is large.